# How do I apply a mean filter on a data set in Python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a data set of 15,497 sets of values. The graph shows the raw data [angle of pendulum vs. sample number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPsXa.png) which, obviously, looks awful. It *should* look like the second picture [filtered data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lunJy.png). A part of the assignment is introducing a mean filter to "smoothen" the data, making it look like the data on the 2nd graph. The data is put into np.array's in Python. But, using np.array's, I can't seem to figure out how to introduce a mean filter.
I'm interested in applying a mean filter on theta in the code [screenshot of Python code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fvJJ.png), as theta are the values on the y axis on the plots. The code is added for you to easily see how the data file is introduced in the code.

Comment: Could you provide us with reproducible data? And preferably code not in screenshot form?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

There is a whole world of filtering techniques. There is a not a single unique 'mean filter'. Moreover, there are causal and non-causal filters (i.e. the difference between not using future values in the filter vs. using the future values in the filter.) I'm going to assume you are desiring a mean filter of size N, as that is pretty standard. Then, to apply this filter, convolve your 'theta' vector with a mean kernel.

I suggest printing the mean kernel and studying how it looks with different N. Then you may understand how it is averaging the values in the signal. I also urge you to think about why convolution is applying this filter to theta. I'll help you by telling you to think about the equivalent multiplication in the frequency domain. Also, investigate the different modes in the convolution function, as this may be more tailored for the specific solution you desire.

```
N=2
mean_kernel = np.ones(N)/N
filtered_sig = np.convolve(sig, mean_kernel, mode='same')
```